# What AD version does Sharepoint 2013 require?

Tags: sharepoint, active-directory, sharepoint-2013

Microsoft's sites only list the required OS version as 2008 R2 SP1, but makes no mention of what version of Active Directory is required.  Where I'm working, we have servers running the correct OS version, but Active Directory is older.  Does anyone know where I can find what AD version Sharepoint 2013 requires in the environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from what I have found 2003 is the lowest version supported

[source](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/62119/can-we-install-sharepoint-2013-with-2012-server-but-the-domain-controller-and-ex)

[source2](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/sharepoint/en-US/eec44f96-8d37-46ab-a931-afc8d568701f/sharepoint-integration-with-exchange-and-active-directory)